# Apache and PHP configuration error

Tags: php, apache

I have recently downloaded PHP 5.5.13 and Apache HTTP Server 2.2 on my windows 7 and confugured both. But when I restart my server I am getting error like "Syntax error on line 240 of C:/Apache/conf/httpd.conf:   Invalid command 'PHPIniDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration." How can I solve this error? And when I am checking the server by writing "//localhost" in my browser its working properly.

Comment: Why not just use [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xampp Webserver where PHP is built-in. Easy to use. For database PhpMyadmin is given together it. Simply Run and Execute just like plug and play

Answer (score 0):

According to this site : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_23943500.html

You have maybe a problem with the defaut port of apache. In the example, defaut port was 80 and already use by another process (or another instance of apache because when you type localhost in your browser it seems to work). 
You can try to change apache port to 8080.